# SqlAlchemy Dynamic Where

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to dynamically select the column I am querying so for example:

```
metadata = MetaData(bind = engine)
booking_table = Table("Bookings",metadata,autoload = True, schema = "SGM")
select_meta = select([booking_table],booking_table.c.event_date==date_string)
conn.execute(select_meta)
```

would be become something like this...

```
def dynamic_search(field,value):
    booking_table = Table("Bookings",metadata,autoload = True, schema = "SGM")
    select_meta = select([booking_table],booking_table.c.field==value)   #Here are the changes
    conn.execute(select_meta)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than accessing the `table.c` by attribute, use the `get` method.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Integer, Column, create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
>>> metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
>>> table = Table("Bookings", metadata,
...     Column('id', Integer(), primary_key=True,),
...     Column('value', Integer(),),
... )
>>> field = 'value'
>>> table.c.get(field)
Column('value', Integer(), table=<Bookings>)
>>> table.c[field]
Column('value', Integer(), table=<Bookings>)
```

So for your example, the code would be something like `booking_table.c[field]`.

Remember to sanitize your inputs; you can probably check for whether `field in table.c`

```
>>> field in table.c
True
>>> 'id' in table.c
True
>>> 'nothere' in table.c
False
```

[Looks like this isn't officially documented](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html?highlight=table.c#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.c), but it works.